# Using shellscript as before launch in intellij debug causes CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, jvm, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug intellij with the below configuration

[image: Shell script]

Now, while trying to add the same script as before launch to the remote jvm debug it says below

[image]

[image: error in intellij]

NOTE: The working directory path is a valid one and does exist although intelli mentions as The system cannot find the path specified.

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue with intellij ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to copy this script content in a scrip file, and switch to the `Script file` tab in Run configuration, configure an interpreter (like cmd, powershell) to see if it helps. The IDEA may default to `\bin\sh` to run the script text and the `\bin\sh` doesn't exist in Windows.

Comment: I've noticed that the same error occurs if you uncheck the "Execute in the terminal" box and then run the shell script configuration directly. Actually the proposal from the comment above works :)